# How to share dynamically created global items or properties between msbuild scripts

Tags: msbuild

How can I share dynamic state between multiple c# project scripts, which reference each other?

I have created a target in a project.targets file and imported it into every project. This target generates an assembly info file with the current svn revision and adds it dynamically to the compiled sources.

This all works fine, but now I would like to improve the target, so that it only creates the assembly info file once (if it does not exist) and shares the path to the generated file across all involved projects.

If I did the build of the referenced projects by myself, I would just pass the shared path property via the MSBuild tasks Properties property, but since the referenced projects are resolved by a target in the Microsoft.Common.targets file, I don't know how to do it.

Furthermore only passing properties is allowed, how is it possible to share items?

Answer (score -1):

You can use TFS API and store all your common configurations in a database. Write code to get the config data from DB or XML and generate your script dynamically or Update on the fly.